# Scroll a container on initial load in an Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a container which animates its scrollTop to the bottom whenever a new item is added. The markup looks something like this:

```
<div class="scrolly">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-animate=" 'scroll-to-bottom' ">
        {{item.value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

This works great when adding new items, but on the initial page load, the container is scrolled to the top. I'd like to figure out the right way to have the scrollTop set to the bottom on initial page load.

Example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bkad/JnwCP/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [scrollGlue](https://github.com/Luegg/angularjs-scroll-glue) which implements this as a directive.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to add some delay when you populate the data like this :)

```
$timeout(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    $scope.items.push({
        value: i
    })
}, 10);
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kuDsr/)**</kbd>